# Creating a non-REST JSON API server with node

Tags: json, node.js, api

I am relatively new to NodeJS, but I'm porting an existing API server written in PHP to use NodeJS. I started out looking at [Express](http://expressjs.com/), but realised that with all the layout-rendering and templating stuff in Express, it wasn't suited for the task. Then I looked at [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/), but realised it's REST-ness wouldn't work with the model of this API.

I don't want anything that is tied to a database, or any specific way of setting out the API endpoints. Is the best solution to fully roll my own server, without the help of any libraries?

**EDIT**: Sorry, it seems I was unclear. I am trying to recreate the PHP API as close as possible, and the PHP version does not use REST. It has a few different PHP scripts which take some POST parameters.

Comment: Sorry... I've gotten a downvote and a close request... would someone mind explaining what is what is wrong with my question?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You have not explained why REST won't work with your API, why specifically Express does not work for your purposes, and what these "endpoints" are.

Comment: Thanks @hexacyanide. I edited the question, hopefully it is more understandable now.

Comment: Why wouldn't Express work? Just don't use "all the layout-rendering and templating stuff"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a simple JSON API, Express is still an option. Layouts, temptating and middleware are optional, and you can just use simpler functions.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // req.body is an object with POST parameters

  // respond with JSON
  res.json(200, { data: 'payload' })

  // or show an error
  res.json(500, { error: 'message' });
});

app.listen(80);
```

That is one of the simplest solutions available. Unless you want to do request body parsing, checking the HTTP request method, other things yourself, then you can create your own server. That would look more like this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    var data = '';

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
      // parse the data
    });
  }
}).listen(80);
```

A method like so would also require checking the path as well as other things that would be handled automatically in Express.